# Leer json desde jquery

Tags: jquery, json

Al querer acceder al valor del título del siguiente `json`

[image: Json]

Con la sentencia `json.message.tittle` estoy obteniendo un indefinido.

¿Como podría tomar el valor tittle?

Comment: trata de visualizar de menos a mas; primero debes ver el primer atributo si te retorna algo colocar un console.log desde el principio ; creo que tu error es que la variable que estas viendo esta en mayuscula  **JSON.message.tittle**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según se puede ver en la imagen que publicas, la propiedad es **`title` (una `t`**) y no `tittle` (*con 2 `t`*).

La sentencia completa debería ser:

`json.message.title[0]`